# String to dictionary conversion

Tags: python, string, dictionary, type-conversion

My code involves importing and exporting usernames and passwords in the form of a dictionary. In order to export the dictionary i changed it in to a string.
This is the imported text file (it is in the same format that the code exports in):

```
{'account1': 'password'}{'account2': 'password'}
```

the code to export is as follows:

```
accounts=open("accounts.txt","r")
accounts=accounts.read()

newaccount={username:password}#user name and password are user defined 
str1=str(newaccount)
updated=open("accounts.txt","w")
updated.write(accounts)
updated.write(str1)
updated.close()
```

I want the dictionary to look like this:

```
{'account1':'password', 'account2':'password'}
```

Comment: Why don't you export your dictionaries in a easier-to-parse format?

Comment: Do no re-invent the wheel, unless it's for training purposes. Dump the dictionary in the file using [json.dump](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#basic-usage) and load it with [json.load](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load)

Comment: I suggest you use `json` object to save your dictionaries, because that way, you won't be able to read it back from your file easily

Comment: Convert the text into a list and update the dictionary from the list.

Comment: Would you mind providing an example of the text you are trying to export into a dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your format is always like posted, you can parse it into dicts by splitting:

```
from ast import literal_eval
with open("in.txt") as f:
    d = {}
    for line in f:
        ds = [literal_eval(ele + "}") for ele in line.split("}") if ele]
        for _d in ds:
           d.update(_d)
    print(d)
```

Which will give  you:

```
{'account2': 'password', 'account1': 'password'}
```

When you want to save it do yourself a favour and use json or pickle i.e:

```
from json import dump, load

dump(d, open("in.txt","w"))
```

Then just load it when you need it:

```
d = load(open("in.txt")))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you turn the string representation of the dictionary back into a dictionary and update it, your method would work:

```
#!python3
import ast

try:
    with open('accounts.txt') as f:
        accounts=ast.literal_eval(f.read())
except FileNotFoundError:
    accounts = {}

username = input('User name? ')
password = input('Password? ')
accounts[username] = password

with open('accounts.txt','w') as f:
    f.write(str(accounts))
```

Example:

```
C:\>test
User name? account1
Password? password

C:\>type accounts.txt
{'account1': 'password'}

C:\>test
User name? account2
Password? password

C:\>type accounts.txt
{'account1': 'password', 'account2': 'password'}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use the python pickle module:

```
import pickle
accounts = {'account1': 'password'}{'account2': 'password'}
pickle.dump( accounts, open( "save.p", "wb" ) )
```

To load the dictionary,

```
accounts = pickle.load( open( "save.p", "rb" ) )
```

You could now modify the dictionary and again save it using `pickle.dump`

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible to load all the accounts in memory? If so, easiest way is to load and write the content as json:

```
import json
with open("accounts.txt", "r") as fp:
   accounts = json.load(fp)
accounts["newUser"] = "password"
with open("accounts.txt", "w") as fp:
   json.dumps(accounts, fp)
```